# Xcode Playground - how to do this?

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

It might sound basic but I can not find a simple example on how to use `Playground` to test an *existing* code.

I have a `view controller` in which I already wrote some code in ( the view controller will add another simple `UIView` from another class I created).

This will run on simulator, but I want to see it live while I edit the code.

If I go `file->new playground`, it will open a playground with an existing code ( an example). I don't want to start rewriting my code into the new playground window.

Even if I try to add my own viewController into the new playground window, he will not recognize any of my project classes and provide error.

How would I run playground on my existing view controller to see the changes live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe Playgrounds is designed for that purpose as it doesn't have a storyboard to view UI code. Look up @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable and implement those into your project. That might serve your purpose better.

Comment: Yea I figured it out to.. I was expecting too much of it.